# Raspberry Pi wpa_supplicant changes not getting saved

Tags: pi-4, wpa-supplicant

Network in `wpa_supplicant.conf` keep coming back after I delete it. Below is my `wpa_supplicant.con`f file

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=IN

network={
    ssid="NETGEAR1"
    psk="xxxxxxx"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    disabled=1
}

network={
    ssid="NETGEAR92"
    psk="xxxxxxx"
}
```

When I am deleting network with `ssid` `NETGEAR1` and save changes it, comes back again after few minutes

Comment: Possibly an SD card that's gone read only.  Try adding a new file using `touch` and rebooting.  If the file does not exist after reboot the card has failed to read-only mode.

Comment: It comes back again after few minutes

Comment: Paste in the output from `mount | grep mmcblk0`.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar - what comes back after a few minutes?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that an application is inserting the network block automagically to be sure that it is available. Wpa_supplicant does allow it with option

```
update_config=1
```

in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. Set this to

```
update_config=0
```

and look if it helps.